# Concatenación de la permutación

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola tengo una función para permutar los posibles resultado, pero me añade al principio `permutacion-`.

```
0: "permutacion.mujer-negro"
1: "permutacion.mujer-rojo"
2: "permutacion.mujer-blanco"
3: "permutacion.nino-negro"
4: "permutacion.nino-rojo"
5: "permutacion.nino-blanco"
```

Quiero quitar el `permutacion.`

```
function generacion_recursiva(tipos, nivel, raiz) {
        if (nivel >= tipos.length - 1) {
        /* Agregamos a cada elemento su nombre separado por un punto */
            return tipos[nivel].variaciones.map(x => [ raiz, x ].join("-"));
        }
        let resultados = [];
        tipos[nivel].variaciones.forEach(elemento => {
            generacion_recursiva(tipos, nivel + 1, [ raiz, elemento ].join(".")).forEach(elemento => {
                resultados.push(elemento);
            });
        });
        return resultados;
    }

let selects = $('.variaciones');
        let tipos = [];
        selects.each(function (indice) {
          // Agregamos un elemento por select encontrado
          tipos[indice] = {
              id: $(this).attr('id'),
            variaciones: $(this).val() || []
          };
        });
        console.log(tipos);
        // Generamos las permutaciones
        var permutas = generacion_recursiva(tipos, 0, 'permutacion');
```

Comment: puedes mostrar lo que tienes en `$('.variaciones')` son selects de opción múltiple?

Comment: Hola @ffflabs son opción multiples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo lo plantearía un poco distinto.

Tu lógica es "  devuelvo N elementos que comienzan por la raíz y terminan en cada variación del nivel actual, concatenando por punto (o guión)"

En el ejemplo mínimo

```
function agregarNivel(variaciones, raiz) {
   return variaciones.map(variacion=>[raiz,variacion].join('.');
}
```

Si llenas eso recursivamente y el nodo padre es "permutación", el resultado tiene la forma

```
 permutación.variacion1
 permutación.variacion2
 permutación.variacion3
 ...
```

Si pasas un string vacío como nodo padre llegarías a

```
 .variacion1
 .variacion2
 .variacion3
```

Tendrías que poner un condicional que es poco elegante:

```
function agregarNivel(variaciones, raiz) {
   return variaciones.map(variacion=> 
          raiz ? [raiz,variacion].join('.') : variacion
}
```

Me parece precario, y en realidad lo que estás haciendo es imitar la lógica de un array. Donde tú concatenas el array añade elementos. La diferencia es que un array no requiere lógica adicional para parchar la adición del primer elemento.

En este ejemplo (dejo el snippet)  usé arreglos a los que voy añadiendo variaciones (en vez de string+concatenar, array+pushear). Recién al obtener el resultado me ocupo de concatenar la salida.

En el nivel inicial le paso un array vacío como raíz.

```js
function generacion_recursiva(tipos, nivel, raiz) {
  if (nivel >= tipos.length - 1) {
    return tipos[nivel].variaciones.map(x => {
      return raiz.concat([x]);
    });
  }
  let resultados = [];
  tipos[nivel].variaciones.forEach(elemento => {
    generacion_recursiva(tipos, nivel + 1, raiz.concat([elemento]))
      .forEach(elemento => {
        resultados.push(elemento);
      });
  });
  return resultados;
}
$('#calcular').on('click', () => {
  let selects = $('.variaciones');
  let tipos = [];
  selects.each(function(indice) {
    // Agregamos un elemento por select encontrado
    tipos[indice] = {
      id: $(this).attr('id'),
      variaciones: $(this).val() || []
    };
  });

  // Generamos las permutaciones
  var permutas = generacion_recursiva(tipos, 0, []).map(res => res.join('.'))
  $('#resultados').empty();
  console.log(permutas);
  permutas.forEach(valor => {
    let optionElement = $(`<option value="${valor}">${valor}</option>`);
    $('#resultados').append(optionElement);
  })


});
```

```css
.titulo {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
}

.variaciones {
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
}

.resultados {
  width: 340px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="titulo">Edad y Género
    <select class="variaciones" multiple id="edad_genero">
      <option value="mujer">mujer</option>
      <option value="niño">niño</option>
      <option value="hombre">hombre</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="titulo">Color
    <select class="variaciones" multiple id="color">
      <option value="negro">negro</option>
      <option value="rojo">rojo</option>
      <option value="blanco">blanco</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="titulo">Material
    <select class="variaciones" multiple id="material">
      <option value="lana">lana</option>
      <option value="algodón">algodón</option>
      <option value="nylon">nylon</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <button id="calcular">Calcular Permutaciones</button>
</div>
<div>
  <select class="resultados" multiple id="resultados">
  </select>
```

Comment: Es estupendo @ffabs funciona perfectamente